Docker Setup Issue with Volumes and Node.js Application Execution
I am working on a Docker setup for a Node.js application that involves a multi-stage build and uses Sequelize for database migrations. However, I'm facing issues with script execution and volume mounting, leading to failures when the Docker container starts.
Environment Details:

Dockerfile:

FROM node:14
ARG ENVIRONMENT_NAME
ARG BUILD_NAME
RUN mkdir -p /app-build
ADD . /app-build
WORKDIR /app-build
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.yarn YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=/root/.yarn yarn --frozen-lockfile
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build:$BUILD_NAME

FROM node:14-alpine
ARG ENVIRONMENT_NAME
ARG BUILD_NAME
RUN mkdir -p /dist
RUN apk add yarn
RUN yarn global add sequelize-cli@6.2.0
RUN yarn add shelljs bull dotenv pg sequelize@6.6.5 nyc

ADD scripts/e2etest.sh /
ADD package.json /
ADD . /
COPY --from=0 /app-build/dist ./dist

CMD ["sh", "./e2etest.sh"]
EXPOSE 9010



Docker Compose:

version: '3'
services:
  db_postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env.docker
    networks:
      - keploy-network

  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: ['redis-server', '--bind', 'redis', '--port', '6379']
    networks:
      - keploy-network

  app:
    container_name: custom_app
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        ENVIRONMENT_NAME: .docker
        BUILD_NAME: docker
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db_postgres
      - redis
    ports:
      - 9010:9010
    env_file:
      - ./.env.docker
    networks:
      - keploy-network
    volumes:
      - /Users/shivamsouravjha/samples-typescript/node-express-graphql-template/.nyc_output:/dist/.nyc_output
    

networks:
  keploy-network:
    external: true


e2etest.sh Script:

#!/bin/sh
set -a . ".env$ENVIRONMENT_NAME" set +a
sleep 10
echo $BUILD_NAME
if [ "$BUILD_NAME" == "local" ]
then
    npx sequelize-cli db:drop
    npx sequelize-cli db:create
fi
echo $LD_PRELOAD
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate

# Seed data for local builds
if [ "$BUILD_NAME" == "local" ]
then
    for file in seeders/*
    do
        npx sequelize-cli db:seed --seed $file
    done
fi

yarn e2etets
# docker cp custom_app:/app-build/dist/nyc_output ./nyc_output_host


The question I've is Why might the /dist/.nyc_output directory be locked or busy in this Docker setup?
I get the error of 
I'm looking for a fix on the volume mounting, so that the nyc output can be copied from docker image to host machine

You should probably delete the volumes: on your app container (but add volumes for persistent storage for db_postgres and possibly redis).  Since you build and install the application in your Dockerfile already, you don't want to overwrite it with potentially unpredictable content from a volume mount.

but would it help me to get the nyc coverage from docker image to host machine?

I'd generally run code coverage tools in my host development environment, without involving containers at all.  If it must run in a container, can you put the output file in a different directory from your source code, so that the volume mount doesn't overwrite anything that's in the image?
